# Maximum Feasible Size For Tidal Mudflats

Tags: environment, geography, tides

Assuming real world physics and an earth-like world, how big of an area could a/some tidal mudflats cover?

Criteria-

- More or less consistently mudflats that are partially submerged at high tides
- Rock outcroppings and high/dry areas between are acceptable

Comment: If for some reason erosion wasn't apparent, I can imagine a whole continent that was 1' underwater at high tide. What size are you looking for? "Biggest" is ambiguous at best and might get the question closed.

Comment: The [Wadden Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wadden_Sea) is about 20 km (12 miles) wide on the average, more in some places, less in others.

Comment: I personally want something big enough that city could hide over the horizon but I'm also just curios to see how big you can go!

Comment: *"Something big enough that city could hide over the horizon":* For a regular person standing on flat ground, the horizon is at about 5 km (3 miles). For an observer atop a 30 meters (100 feet) tall hill or tower, the horizon is at about 20 km (12 miles). The real world Wadden Sea is ample for the first case, and just about sufficient for the second. But then, of course, comes the case that an observer standing on top of a 30 meters tall hill is looking at a 30 meters tall tower, and in this case you need 40 km (25 miles) between them.

Comment: You would be better off picking a size and asking if it is possible, the maximum theoretical size would be very difficult to ascertain.

Answer (score 2):

[According to UNESCO](https://whc.unesco.org/en/list/1314/#:%7E:text=The%20Wadden%20Sea%20is%20the,Wadden%20Sea%20maritime%20conservation%20area.), the largest tidal mudflats on Earth is the Wadden Sea, at nearly 6,000 square miles (15,500 km) of unbroken tidal mudflats, so it wouldn't be a stretch to have one of a similar size on a different but similar planet.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I have edited it to correct my conversion error. I feel kind of silly having missed that. Believe it or not, I actually have a degree in math.

Answer (score 2):

There is an upper limit on how large mudflats can get.

This point would be reached when the height of the tides flows as far as it can, in the period between tides. Preferably without flowing in such volumes as to cause erosion of the material they are flowing over that exceeds the deposition rate. The inundation level and climate must also be such that the mudflat does not get taken over by a mangrove swamp, but remains a flat and exposed surface.

The math for this greatly exceeds me, but looking at examples from earth the deepest (greatest extend from permanent water to permanent land) mudflats seem to be some 8km from the nearest dry land, although they may be "anchored" around islands, such as the Frisian Islands of the Wadden sea, and they may border "rivers" of deeper water that penetrate the mudflats.

There is a right scholarly paper about this to be found at : https://www.waddensea-worldheritage.org/sites/default/files/1999_mudflats-worldwide.pdf
It lists all of the world's major mudflats and tidal flats(not quite the same thing!), criteria for their formation, wildlife statistics, and a host more.

Answer (score 0):

As big as you want. With a big moon  high tie could  be many many feet higher so if there is a beach or plains biome and at high tide most of it will be underwater.

Comment: It's not the height of the tide that's the limiting factor: it's the *time* between high tide and low tide. Height is immaterial: the Bay of Fundy has 15 meter tides, yet the flats exposed are nowhere near the largest in the world.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, assume a duplicate of Earth and the moon. Actual calculations will vary depending on variation such as length of day and the length of the month, so we'll stick with Earth as an example.

The maximum width of a tidal flat, roughly speaking, can defined by the maximum tidal current multiplied by the time between high tide and low tide. Now, obviously, it's more complicated than that: among other things, the tidal current doesn't simply flow at max speed in and then max speed out, it depends on the togopraphy of the coast and the height of the tide, and so on, but it does give you an upper bound. On Earth, you get two tidal cycles per lunar day, which is 24 hours and 50 minutes, or roughly 6.2 hours from high tide to low tide. If you have a 10 knot tidal current, and a very low slope, then the maximum possible *theoretical* width would be 62 nautical miles.

However, reality has to set in: at no point will it actually get that far. The tidal current slackens and then accelerates and then falls again. Realistically, 30 nautical miles might be the theoretical maximum. But again, this all depends a lot more factors, including the period you have between tides.